# Compare the contents of a field with an input from the textboc in ms access using visual basic

Tags: ms-access

good day! I would like to ask how can I compare the contents of a field in ms access? thanks. I am trying to compare an input from the textbox to a field in ms access. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Say for example you have a un bound Text Box called TextBoxName and another Text Box which is bound to a field called CompanyName and itself is called TextBoxCompanyName.

Then the VBA code to compare the contents would look similar to the following:

```
If Me.TextBoxName = Me.TextBoxCompanyName Then
    MsgBox "Values are the same", vbExclamation, "Identical"
Else
    MsgBox "Values are different", vbExclamation, "Different"
End If
```